# Sign out not working if deployed to IIS as a web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Good morning. We have an asp .net core 2.1 with Angular application.
We use asp.net identity.
To logout users we use await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
It works fine running the application in visual studio and deploying to a root website, but if we deploy to a webapplication inside a website in IIS, the logout doesn't work at all.
I assumed that the SignOutAsync deleted all information server side so even if the cookies were not modified, the server would reject any future request, but it seems it isn't.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems solved.
Using await **_signInManager**.SignOutAsync(); works fine.

I don't know the difference regarding using HttpContext.SignOutAsync()

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Asp.net Core Identity ,so the authentication ticket in inside in `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie , you can try to delete the cookie by set specific scheme :

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
```

But use `SignInManager.SignOutAsync()` is better which will delete below cookies :

```
await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme);
```